# Как вовремя перебора массива (foreach) сравнить значение ключа текущей итерации с ключом из предыдущей и вывести результат по условию?

Tags: php, foreach

Я только осваиваю язык, просьба не пинать если что. 
Я получаю данные из SQL в такой массив.

```
$arr[0]= array('order_num'=>'123');
$arr[1]= array('order_num'=>'123');
$arr[2]= array('order_num'=>'456');
```

Раскладываю его так:

```
tr>
    <th>Номер заказа</th>
</tr>
 <?
 foreach ($arr as $item) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$item['order_num']?></td>
    </tr>
 <?}?>
```

Нужно разложить значение в таблицу с условием, если $item['order_num'] повторяется(в данном примере "123"), то выводить:

```
<tr class='same'>
    <td><?=$item['order_num']?></td>
</tr>
```

если не повторяется, выводить так:

```
<tr class='another_class'>
    <td><?=$item['order_num']?></td>
</tr>
```

Помогите с кодом пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсчитайте количество повторений номеров в исходном массиве, на его основе и выбирайте класс.

```
$dups = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'order_num'));

foreach($data as $row){
    ...
    $cls = dups[$row['order_num']] == 1 ? "first" : "second";
    ... // <td class="<?= $cls ?>"

}
```

Хотя *"повторяется"*, видимо имелось в виду две одинаковых строки подряд. Т.е. чередовать, и одинаковые выводить с одним классом

```
$num = null;
$clsIdx = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
    if($num != $row['order_num']){
       $num = $row['order_num'];
       $clsIdx++;
    } 
    echo ($clsIdx % 2) ? "first" : "second";

}
```

Comment: Первый код, то что нужно. Спасибо большое! Сильно помогли. Я их из SQL уже отсортированными по номеру забираю, Работает как надо.

Comment: За второй код вообще отдельное спасибо=) в итоге буду его использовать.